# Repeating calendar events and some final maths

Tags: mysql

I am trying to have a go at the infamous repeating events on calendars using PHP/MySQL. I've finally found something that seems to work. I found my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5186095/158126) but I'm having a little difficulty finishing it off.

My first table 'events'.

```
ID    NAME
1     Sample Event
2     Another Event
```

My second table 'events_meta that stores the repeating data.

```
ID    event_id      meta_key           meta_value
1     1             repeat_start       1336312800 /* May 7th 2012 */
2     1             repeat_interval_1  432000 /* 5 days */
```

With repeat_start being a date with no time as a unix timestamp, and repeat_interval an amount in seconds between intervals (432000 is 5 days).

I then have the following MySQL which I modified slightly from the above link. The timestamp used below (1299132000 which is 12th May 2012) is the current day with no time.

```
SELECT EV.*
FROM `events` EV
RIGHT JOIN `events_meta` EM1 ON EM1.`event_id` = EV.`id`
RIGHT JOIN `events_meta` EM2 ON EM2.`meta_key` = CONCAT( 'repeat_interval_', EM1.`id` )
WHERE EM1.meta_key = 'repeat_start'
    AND (
        ( CASE ( 1336744800 - EM1.`meta_value` )
            WHEN 0
              THEN 1
            ELSE ( 1336744800 - EM1.`meta_value` ) / EM2.`meta_value`
          END
        )
    ) = 1
```

In the above MySQL, the following code deducts the repeat_start field (`EM1.'meta_value'`) from the current date and then divides it by the repeat interval field (`EM2.'meta_value'`).

```
ELSE ( 1336744800 - EM1.`meta_value` ) / EM2.`meta_value`
```

OR

```
TODAYS DATE - START DATE / 5 DAYS
```

So here's the maths:

```
1336744800 - 1336312800 = 432000
432000 / 432000 = 1
```

Now that works perfect. But if I change the current timestamp 5 days ahead to 1336312800 which is 17th Mat 2012, it looks a bit like this:

```
1336312800 - 1336312800 = 864000
86400 / 432000 = 2
```

Which doesn't work because it equals 2 and in the MySQL it needs to equal 1. So I guess my question is, how do I get the MySQL to recognise a whole number rather than having to do this?

```
...
WHERE EM1.meta_key = 'repeat_start'
    AND (
        ( CASE ( 1336744800 - EM1.`meta_value` )
            WHEN 0
              THEN 1
            ELSE ( 1336744800 - EM1.`meta_value` ) / EM2.`meta_value`
          END
        )
    ) = IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,....)
```

Hope I'm making sense and I hope it's just a simple maths thing or a function that MySQL has that will help :) Thanks for your help!

**EDIT: THE ANSWER**

Thanks to @eggypal below, I found my answer and of course it was simple!

```
SELECT EV.*
FROM elvanto_calendars_events AS EV
RIGHT JOIN elvanto_calendars_events_meta AS EM1 ON EM1.`event_id` = EV.`id`
RIGHT JOIN elvanto_calendars_events_meta AS EM2 ON EM2.`meta_key` = CONCAT( 'repeat_interval_', EM1.`id` )
WHERE EM1.meta_key = 'repeat_start'
AND ( ( 1336744800 - EM1.`meta_value` ) % EM2.`meta_value`) = 0
```

Comment: Date math based on timestamps and fixed number of seconds in a day will break on Daylight Savings.

Comment: Good call @DCoder. I store all my times as GMT and then use the CONVERT_TZ function to determine the `repeat_start` date. The above code examples doesn't include this extra code. I think that should do the trick right?

Comment: will your query allow me to see the result for the given start date and end date? `1336744800 ` looks like a specific day :(

Comment: I started following it and failed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286332/display-next-event-date

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want your query to *do*, but the jist of your question makes me lean toward suggesting that you look into modular arithmetic: in SQL, `a % b` returns the *remainder* when `a` is divided by `b` - if there is no remainder (i.e. `a % b = 0`), then `a` must be an *exact multiple* of `b`.

In your case, I *think* you're trying to find events where the time between the event start and some given literal is an exact multiple of the event interval: that is,  `(literal - event_start) % event_interval = 0`.  If it's non-zero, the value is the time to the next occurrence after `literal` (and, therefore, to determine whether that next occurrence occurs within some period of time, say a day, one would test to see if the remainder is less than such constant e.g. `(literal - event_start) % event_interval < 86400`).

If this isn't what you're after, please clarify exactly what your query is trying to achieve.

Comment: That's the trick! I managed to get it working in PHP: `echo ((strtotime('2012-05-22 00:00:00')- 1336312800) % 432000);` I tried using the `%` in MySQL but it didn't work. Is their an equivalent?

Comment: Sorry, ignore my last comment, it worked! I'll edit my original post with the final code to help others out :)

Comment: I started following it and failed. Help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286332/display-next-event-date

Answer (score -1):

set @dat_ini = '2023-05-20',@dat_fim = '2022-11-20'; select (DATEDIFF( @dat_fim,@dat_ini )) % 60

THIS < 10

It only works for a short period.

To do this, take the start date and change the Month that is on the screen and add a year, then subtract it from the start date, then it works.

[image]