# SQL Version of CONCAT and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Trying to follow [Calendar Recurring/Repeating Events - Best Storage Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183630/calendar-recurring-repeating-events-best-storage-method) to design the database using SQL Server 2005.

When i run this below query

```
SELECT EV.*
FROM events EV
RIGHT JOIN events_meta EM1 ON EM1.event_id = EV.id
RIGHT JOIN events_meta EM2 ON EM2.meta_key = CONCAT( 'repeat_interval_', EM1.id )
WHERE EM1.meta_key = 'repeat_start'
    AND (
        ( CASE ( 1299132000 - EM1.meta_value )
            WHEN 0
              THEN 1
            ELSE ( 1299132000 - EM1.meta_value )
          END
        ) / EM2.meta_value
    ) = 1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I am getting `'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

I searched and seems like it is supported only in SQL Server 2012. How can i acheive this with SQL Server 2005/2008? *Also what about LIMIT syntax in SQL Server?*

I want the above sql version of query.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server equivalent of limit is [TOP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx). e.g

```
SELECT TOP 10 ID
FROM    Table.
```

TOP is not really synomonous with LIMIT, because you can't pass 2 arguments to it, (e.g. LIMIT 10, 20) to specify the starting point. In SQL Server 2012 the equivalent is [OFFSET FETCH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx), but in 2005 and 2008 versions you need to use [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and filter on the value of this, e.g.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT *, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID)
            FROM    T
        ) t
WHERE   t.RowNumber BETWEEN 10 AND 30;
```

You can just use `+` to [concatenate strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
SELECT 'a' + 'b'
```

SQL Server 2012 introduces the [CONCAT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) function

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent function in SQL Server to CONCAT() is + and you can limit the resultset by using the TOP keyword.

Write your query as:

```
SELECT TOP 30 EV.*
FROM events EV
RIGHT JOIN events_meta EM1 ON EM1.event_id = EV.id
RIGHT JOIN events_meta EM2 ON EM2.meta_key = 'repeat_interval_' + CAST (EM1.id as varchar(10)) -- cast is required in case id column is int
WHERE EM1.meta_key = 'repeat_start'
    AND (
        ( CASE ( 1299132000 - EM1.meta_value )
            WHEN 0
              THEN 1
            ELSE ( 1299132000 - EM1.meta_value )
          END
        ) / EM2.meta_value
    ) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

assumed that EM1.id is of type int you first have to **convert it to a varchar**.
**To concatenate use the `+` operator**. And use **TOP instead of LIMIT in Sql-server**.

This should work:

```
SELECT TOP 30 EV.*
FROM events EV
RIGHT JOIN events_meta EM1 ON EM1.event_id = EV.id
RIGHT JOIN events_meta EM2 ON EM2.meta_key = ('repeat_interval_' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), EM1.id))
WHERE EM1.meta_key = 'repeat_start'
    AND (
        ( CASE ( 1299132000 - EM1.meta_value )
            WHEN 0
              THEN 1
            ELSE ( 1299132000 - EM1.meta_value )
          END
        ) / EM2.meta_value
    ) = 1
```

Comment: I question the fact that this is tested (at least on the correct DBMS) since `LIMIT` is not SQL Server Syntax...

Comment: Oh, thank you. You're right of course. Updated the code. I tested the main issue (concatenation).