# iCalendar database schema

Tags: database-schema, icalendar

Where can I find the iCalendar database schema? The best I can find is the [xml schema](http://www.calconnect.org/artifacts/ical-art.shtml).

I could use that I suppose but that's a lot of work and I am hoping someone has done it already.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you are actually talking about?

Comment: Hi Evert, thanks for asking. iCalendar is a standard for creating calendar data. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar. There's a good standard, but nowhere can I find a nice easy database schema for it...

Comment: I know what iCalendar is, I wrote a popular library for it :) The part you should elaborate on is the database schema. iCalendar is usually transmitted as a stream of bytes, so from that perspective a `BLOB` is a sane column type to store it.

Comment: Ah nice! What library did you write? So my se case is that I want a calendar back end to use for a jquery [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/ "FullCalendar") calendar. So I want to be able to query the calendar for a range of dates and get back the events. The problem is that the calendars will grow fairly large and I don't want to load the whole calendar into memory every time I need to query it. I also (for now) only need events, not journals or anything else. Based on what I've read, I am thinking I will store events in an event table. The table will have start and end date, and then...

Comment: ...store the full event in one blob column. Then I can query for the events within a period, load them into a calendar in [DDay ical](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/pages/projects/dday.ical/ "DDay iCal"), query them for the dates applicable, and return back a json event list. What do you think?

Comment: It's [this library](http://sabre.io/vobject) ;). The biggest problem with what you want to do, is keeping recurrence in mind, which means you definitely need a good recurrence parser. We store entire iCalendar objects in blobs, but then denormalize the view fields we need indexes for, such as start and end time.

Comment: But back to the context of this question. I don't think you're going to find something that's ready-made somehow, unless you simply run an existing CalDAV server.

Comment: maybe it would be more readable if you update your question instead of putting details in comments;)

Answer (score 10):

Summarizing the comments and adding my own two cents:

- There is no such thing as *the* iCalendar database schema.
- Since iCalendar is just some BLOB, in the easiest case you might just store it as a single string field.
- Since you want to query by time-range, you'll probably want at least separate fields for that.
- Recurring events are tricky to get right, because many complicated things can be constructed with iCalendar's RRULEs

  - [Calendar Recurring/Repeating Events - Best Storage Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183630/calendar-recurring-repeating-events-best-storage-method)
  - For [khal](https://github.com/geier/khal), we decided to simply generate a cache for the next X decades. That means a separate table that maps each event from the event table to a lot of datetime-ranges, which are generated according to the RRULES.

Answer (score 0):

How about building your database in JSON-LD built on top of ical specifications?
Example can be found [here](https://json-ld.org/playground/), under Event tab:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "ical": "http://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/ical#",
    "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
    "ical:dtstart": {
      "@type": "xsd:dateTime"
    }
  },
  "ical:summary": "Lady Gaga Concert",
  "ical:location": "New Orleans Arena, New Orleans, Louisiana, USA",
  "ical:dtstart": "2011-04-09T20:00:00Z"
}
```