# Checking if a calendar event reminder is due

Tags: android, ios, calendar, push-notification, google-calendar-api

I wonder how calendar event reminder alerts are typically generated for cloud-based apps like iCalendar, Google Calendar, etc. I'm guessing that the storage method would be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5186095/233798), but how are alerts triggered, e.g., 10mins before an event is due?

Constantly querying the db doesn't seem clever.

Do these calendar apps receive push notifications from the server or are the alerts generated locally on the device?

Thanks